# Where do I put the collation clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the query below:

```
SELECT IDNUMBER  collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS       AS ciscrimeurn,
       WID              AS nicheoccurrenceid,
       OccurrenceFileNo AS nicheoccurrencefilno
FROM   [rmslive\sql2005].NicheRMS_Live.dbo.TBL_GOCCID
       INNER JOIN [rmslive\sql2005].NicheRMS_Live.dbo.tbl_goccurrence
               ON tbl_goccid.wid = tbl_goccurrence.id
WHERE  tbl_goccid.ID LIKE '2060609955%'
UNION
SELECT NULL             AS ciscrimeurn,
       id               AS nicheoccurrenceid,
       occurrencefileno AS nicheoccurrencefilno
FROM   [rmslive\sql2005].NicheRMS_Live.dbo.tbl_goccurrence
WHERE  id NOT LIKE '90309955%'
EXCEPT
SELECT CISIDNumber collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
       OccurrenceID,
       OccurrenceFileNo
FROM   dbNicheCIS
```

NicheRMS_Live and dbNicheCIS have different collations.  Both are SQL server databases.

ciscrimeurn is a varchar, nicheoccurrenceid is a decimal and OccurrenceFileNo is an integer.  I do not understand where to put the collation clause.

Comment: check this out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405316/sql-server-2008-database-collation-conversion

Comment: Collation controls the order of sorting strings and characters. So use it on the applicable column type, in this case, your ciscrimeurn field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want change column collation then

```
SELECT columnName COLLATE COLLATION_NAME
FROM   tableName
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have amended the query in the question incorporating what you said but I still get the error.  Could you take a look?

Comment: @w0051977 what about OccurrenceID,OccurrenceFileNo